# Mysql - how to get data for two foreign key columns of same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database

1. Table: `users` with  columns: `id`, `username`, `email` etcs
2. Table: `users_messages` with  columns: `id`, `to`, `from`, `messages`, `sent_time`

Columns `to` and `from` are keys `users` from `users` table. Issue is that I need to:
"select all users to and from username and message".

For instance if table row is like below:

```
From, To,   Message
11,   14,   Hi, How are you
14,   11,   Hello,
```

and if 11 is john and 14 is mark, then I need output like this:

```
From,   To,     Message
john,   mark,   Hi, How are you
mark,   john,   Hello,
```

With my query I can only get username for from column or to column but not for both. How can I perform a query that gives me from and to both usernames?

The following query gives me empty result:

```
SELECT  u.username, m.message, m.from, m.to  
FROM  `users_messages` m,  `users` u
where 
m.from = u.id and  m.to = u.id

LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I have tried other queries, but not able to get the desired output. Do I need a self join as well for messages table?

Comment: the example you added is not good both uses appears in both columns in `to` as well as in `from`

Comment: the table structure is like that, to , from, and message ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT u1.username AS "sender", u2.username AS "recipient", m.message, m.from, m.to  
FROM `users_messages` m
LEFT JOIN `users` u1 ON (u1.id = m.from)
LEFT JOIN `users` u2 ON (u2.id = m.to)
WHERE m.from = XX OR m.to = XX
```

Comment: @Jiří Chmiel. Thanks for the answer. Let me try this but will we need where clause as well?? after doing joins??

Comment: No. It would be required if you want to select message for a particular user.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
   select u.`name` as `FROM`, u2.`name` as `TO`, `Message` 
   from users_messages um 
   inner join users u On um.`From` = u.id
   inner join users u2 On um.`To` = u2.id
   LIMIT 0 , 30
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/248fd/15)

if you want to get specified messages from one user add this

```
  WHERE u.`name` = 'mark' // to get messages FROM mark
```

or this

```
  WHERE u2.`name` = 'mark'  // to get messages TO mark
```

Comment: This query does not include messages that have no set either "from" or "to" column.

Answer (score 0):

Yes self join can help you achieve the desired output :

```
SELECT  u1.username, m.message, u2.username 
FROM  users_messages m,  users u1, users u2
where 
m.from = u1.id and  m.to = u2.id

LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Assuming : from and to will not have null values

Comment: Use this query i don't have a setup for this. If you think it is the right solution please accept the answer and up vote it.

Comment: I've tried it and this does not work. I get 0's for to and from columns and it's not even properly named on the result table.